# 'int' object is not iterable error (Project Euler 4)

Tags: python, typeerror, palindrome

I am currently working on Project Euler Problem 4 (https://projecteuler.net/problem=4) and am consistently getting an error when I try to run my code. I have looked at other questions regarding the 'int' object is not iterable, but have not found one that has helped me so far. Here is my current code:

```
# Euler 4
# Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers
j = []
i = None
for x,y in range(1,1000):
    j.append(x*y)

    for i in range(1,j.length):
        if (str(j[i]))[::-1] == str(j[i]):
            print j
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Daniel Bashir\Desktop\HMC\Projects\Python\Project Euler\PE4.py", line 5, in <module>
    for x,y in range(1,1000):
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Most of the fixes I have seen for this for loop issue involve changing "for a in b" to "for a in range...", but I already have that syntax here.

Could anyone help me figure out what is wrong?

Any general comments about my code are also welcome. I'm just a beginner!

Comment: What do you think `range(1, 1000)` produces? What do you expect each `x` and `y` to be?

Comment: If you're a beginner, I'd _very highly recommend_ completing a class or tutorial before jumping into coding challenges.

Comment: Following up on TigerhawkT3's first comment, `x, y` is _not_ the same as a lone `x` followed by a lone `y`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I see that this isn't exactly the way to produce all of the products of numbers from 1 to 1000... I'll think about this some more.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I have done a few tutorials/classes! I still consider myself a relative novice, though.

Answer (score 1):

range(start, end) yields integers

using this

```
for x,y in range(1,1000):
```

you are trying to iterate over an integer (1)
you can't iterate over an integer

you want

```
for x in range(1,1000):
```

Comment: To clarify, `range(start, end)` doesn't return an integer - it yields integers when you iterate over it.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 true dat. Otherwise you would be stuck in an infinite loop! updated.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying (without realizing it) to iterate over each integer yielded by the `range` function:

```
for x,y in range (1,1000):
    j.append(x*y)
```

The comma in `x,y` makes those three characters a single 2-tuple, which is *not* the same as two variables `x` and `y`... especially when they're on the left-hand side of an assignment statement.  Yes, `for` is an assignment statement --- about a thousand of them, in your case --- with the `x,y` tuple on the left side and an integer on the right:

```
(x, y) = 1     # TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
(x, y) = 2     # It never gets this far...
#...
(x, y) = 1000  # ...but it's trying to.
```

Assigning to a tuple uses **sequence unpacking** (described at the end of the "[Tuples and Sequences](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences)" section), which iterates over the values and assigns them to the variables inside the tuple.  But there is no sequence of values in your code, only an `int`, which leads directly to the "'int' object is not iterable" error message.

As [luke_aus answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888087/4116239), you can solve the immediate problem by replacing the tuple with a lone variable, but that means `y` never gets assigned:

```
for x in range(1, 1000):
    j.append(x * y)  # NameError: name 'y' is not defined
```

In this case, though, you don't need `y` at all.  It's always equal to `x`, so just use `x`:

```
for x in range(1, 1000):
    j.append(x * x)
```

Or, if you really *will* need that `y` later, just assign `y` whenever "later" happens:

```
for x in range(1, 1000):
    j.append(x * x)
    #...
    y = something_else()  # Later is now!
    do_something_with_both(x, y)
```